# In HTML javascript function with parameter can't pass to jQuery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have simple HTML login code in which i am passing `formID` and `divID` as parameter of javascript & jQuery function but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
session_start();

<html>
    <head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function formToResultSwitch(formID,divID){
            $.ajax({ 
                type:"POST",
                url:"connection.php",
                data: $(formID).serialize(),
                success: function(response){$(divID).html(response);}
            }); //return false;

        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="result">
        <form method="post" id="form1" action="" onSubmit="javascript:formToResultSwitch('#form1','#result')">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="78">Username</td>
                    <td width="6">:</td>
                    <td width="294"><input name="username" type="text" id="username"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input name="password" type="text" id="password"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>                 
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
                </form>
             </div>
          </body>
    </html>
```

If I put `#form1` and `#result` directly in function than it works perfectly. But if I passed it value threw parameter than not worked with ajax part. How can I passed value threw parameter in this function?

Connection.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {                     
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['password'];
    $use = $_SESSION['user'];
    $pas = $_SESSION['pass'];
    echo "session variable stored";
    echo $use." ".$pas; 

    $data = explode('.',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']); // Get the sub-domain here
    $username = $_SESSION['user']; 
    $password = $_SESSION['pass'];

    if (!empty($data[0])) {
        $subdomain = $data[0];// The * of *.mydummyapp.com will be now stored in $subdomain

        echo "<html><head></head><body><table>";
        echo "<tr>$subdomain</tr>"; 
    }

    $mhost = 'localhost';
    $muser = 'root';
    $mpassword = '';
    $mdatabase = 'test1';
    $sitedbh = mysqli_connect($mhost, $muser, $mpassword, $mdatabase);

    if(!$sitedbh){ echo "<tr>connection prob</tr>"; }
    else {

        $qr = "select id, username, dbusername, dbpassword, dbid from clients where subdomain='$subdomain' and username='$username' and password='$password'";
        $sitemysql = mysqli_query($sitedbh, $qr)
            or die("error: " . mysqli_error());

        $appdata = mysqli_fetch_array($sitemysql);
    }

    if (empty($appdata)) {
        // If the client does not exist i.e. the end-user types the wrong sub-domain
        echo "Oops! Sorry, we are unable to find you! Please email us at support@mydummyapp.com";
        exit();
    }

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = $appdata[2];
    $password = $appdata[3];
    $database = 'test1'.$appdata[4];

    $dbh = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

    if(!$dbh) { echo "<tr>connection prob</tr>"; }
    else {
        $result = mysqli_query($dbh, "SELECT role FROM table1 where username='$appdata[1]'") or die("error: " . mysqli_error());

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data = $row[0];
            echo $data;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "session not on";
}
?>
```

Comment: close your php tag on the top

Comment: Have you tried alerting the parameters in the top of your function to make sure they're being passed in without worrying about the ajax end?

Comment: Any errors on the JS console? Does the HTTP request show up in the Net tab of the developer tools?

Comment: @intracept: yes i passed alert throwout function and i got it doesn't go inside ajax.

Comment: *"but it doesn't work"* is not a helpful error description.

Comment: @susheel: sorry its my mistake here.i closed it but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3640336 what about alerting `$(formID).serialize()`?  I agree with @Quentin with regard to looking for javascript errors.

Comment: check now. does that work

Comment: I wonder if divid is still in scope in the success

Answer (score 0):

**jquery:**

```
function formToResultSwitch(formID,divID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "connection.php",
        data: $(formID).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $(divID).html(response);
        }
    });            
    return false; // return false to stop the default submit functionality
}
```

`return formToResultSwitch('#form1', '#result')` added this because if function returns something we need to have return before calling it.

**html:**

```
<form method="post" id="form1" action="" onSubmit="return formToResultSwitch('#form1', '#result')">
```

Comment: Are you playing the "spot the difference" game, or what?

Comment: You still didn't point out what you changed and why/how that solves the problem at hand (and what the problem actually is).

Comment: let me add more modifications

Comment: So, you are saying that it only *appears* that the Ajax call doesn't "work" because the form submits and the page refreshes? That could be indeed the case.

Comment: some one downvoted. can that be taken back as i edited the answer correctly

Comment: @FelixKling:it doesn't show any error thats why i can't described it.

Comment: @user3640336: You can add `console.log` statements and check whether `formToResultSwitch` is called at all. Then whether the success callback is called or not. Check the network tab whether the Ajax call is made or not. These are all basic debugging steps.

Comment: @FelixKling I put alert before ajax script that alert worked but after that it doen't show result. It just refresh page.

Comment: @user3640336

`connection.php` show us this code 
by the way i have done changes please try that. its working fine fine. only thing i need connection.php code

Comment: @user3640336: *"It just refresh page."* See, that's an important piece of information. It means that the form gets submitted. You want to prevent that.

Comment: as per my answer above, ajax problem would be solved. error might be in the connection.php but still ajax should work with showing errors in the result div if there is any. please do the changes in form tag and add return false.